# Why won't File.copy work with Server.MapPath

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to do something really simple but its taking longer to figure out than it should.

So I have this copy method which works where both the source file and destination are string values.

Hard coded values work

```
Dim copyPath As String ="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\somesite.com\someFolder\dink1\muffin.gif"
Dim copyPath2 As String = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\somesite.com\someFolder\dink2\muffin.gif"
File.Copy(copyPath, copyPath2)
```

But this doesn't work

```
Dim copyPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/someFolder/dink1/" + fileName)
Dim copyPath2 As String = Server.MapPath("~/someFolder/dink2/" + fileName)
File.Copy(copyPath, copyPath2)
```

What do I need to do to properly build out the paths here?

Comment: Did you verify what copyPath and copyPath2 contain? Also - do you get an error message?

Comment: Add code that asserts both code paths return the same strings. Tell us what happens (File.Copy does not 'know' how the strings were build).

Comment: Have you check Folder is Exist on server or not.

Comment: @Yuriy There are no errors

Comment: If there are no errors, then what 'doesn't work'?

Comment: Thanks Frank. That was it. Response.write showed me that while I had the path, the value for the file name was being lost despite having a string value to hold it. I have it resolved now that I saw the file name was what was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath` is a secure method, and requires that you have `AspEnableParentPaths` set to true for your application.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)